# Instagram api not returning my following list

Tags: javascript, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to get following list using Instagram API([Follows](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#get_users_follows)) so i have generated an access_token and now I am trying to call this URL

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=my_access_token`

but it always returns this response even when I am following multiple people

`{"pagination": {}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}`

When I call this method it returns my profile data

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=my_access_token`

I am using a sandbox client and my Instagram account is an admin of that client.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: title and content contradicts. are you trying to get your followers or the people you follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sandbox mode, you will only see the sandbox approved users in the following list, add one of the users you follow to sandbox mode, and it will show just that user as your following.

Comment: This is correct. If you're having trouble understanding, here's a short write-up explaining how [Instagram Sandbox mode works](https://medium.com/@emersonthis/instagram-on-websites-the-new-landscape-62c91d733894#.4z8g35g2s)